# Better to have a contexts and providers folder or only a contexts folder in React project

Tags: reactjs, react-context, project-structure

In my React Typescript project I have a `Context` and a `Context Provider` function:

**Context:**

```
export const MyContext = createContext<null | MyContextType>(null);
```

**Context Provider**

```
export const MyContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
    // code here
    }
```

Is it better, more a convention to create a folder `contexts` and export both function from a context file e.g. `MyContext.tsx`

Or create another folder: `providers` and create another provider file there `MyContextProvider.tsx`?

Comment: This is a stylistic question that is purely up to you. Neither option is "better" by any factual method of measurement